# How to validate thrown javascript exception using chai and mocha?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, chai-as-promised

I have MongoDB Query function which in which query params are validated
Here is the function 
Note: user is mongoose model

```
function fetchData(uName)
{
    try{
        if(isParamValid(uName))
        {
            return user.find({"uName":uName}).exec()
        }
        else {
            throw "Invalid params"
        }
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        throw e
    }
}
```

To test this with invalid username values, I have written test code for that using mocha, chai, and chai-as-promised for promise-based functions

```
describe('Test function with invalid values', async ()=>{
    it('should catch exception', async () => {
        await expect(fetchData(inValidUserName)).to.throw()
    })

    it('should catch exception', async () => {
        await expect(fetchData(inValidUserName)).to.throw(Error)
    })

    it('should catch exception', async () => {
        await expect(fetchData(inValidUserName)).to.be.rejectedWith(Error)
    })

    it('should catch exception', async () => {
        await expect(fetchData(inValidUserName)).to.be.rejected
    })
})
```

None of them pass the test, How do I write a test case to handle exception for invalid userName values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the result of `fetchData` function call to `expect` function. Instead of calling the `fetchData` function inside `expect` function, pass a function to `expect` function.

```
it('should catch exception', async () => {
    await expect(() => fetchData(inValidUserName)).to.throw('Invalid params')
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works for me
Do I need to change test code if I replace throw new Error("Invalid params") from throw "Invalid params" ??

Comment: I don't think that you will need to change anything

Answer (score 0):

Use `try/catch`

```
it('should catch exception', async () => {
    try {
      await fetchData(inValidUserName);
    } catch(error) {
      expect(error).to.exist;
    }
})
```

Comment: This solution will not work. Coz In this case, If fetchData function does not throw exception/error for invalidValues it will still pass the test case